# Change default install dir in WiX Toolset

Tags: wix

I want the default directory to be: `C:\MyApp`
Unfortunately, whatever I do, the default directory is still `C:\Program Data(x86)\MyApp`.

How can I change it?
My current directory structure looks like this:

```
 <SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]"/>
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
      <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="MyApp"/>
    </Directory>
 </Directory>
```

Can you explain to me, what am I doing wrong?
Greetings

Comment: Does this help? http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-Change-Default-Install-Location-td1092961.html

Comment: @KlausGütter nope, I am using WixUI_Advanced and the default location is still in the Programs Data

Comment: Why not install in the right place?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I want the default install dir to be "C:\MyApp". There is no right place, it's up to the client

Comment: All binaries on Windows are supposed to go into Program Files (or marginally in the System folder and sometimes in the user profile). Only problems result from everyone making their own standard.